# ASP.NET: Does "Image control" have any other attribute that's used to get data besides ImageUrl?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I've been struggling for a couple of days now on how to keep **FileUpload** web control data locate in a **Wizard** web control. When I go to a different step from the one in which the FileUpload control is located, the data is lost.

I've come across this article that shows how to keep the whole FileUpload Control in a Session State ([How to Maintain FileUpload Control’s State after PostBack](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/101834/How-to-Maintain-FileUpload-Control-s-State-after-P.aspx)).

In this article, the author uses session to store data

```
Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
```

Now, thanks to the article, I'm able to keep a copy of the FileUpload control in the session and am able to invoke it in any wizard step I want.

Now, I'd like to know how, after re-creating the FileUpload control saved in the Session

```
FileUpload fp = (FileUpload)Session["FileUpload1"];
```

I can use that data from it to display the image that was uploaded.

```
Image1.ImageUrl =
```

It looks like using the **ImageUrl** attribute is the wrong way of doing it. So Is there any way I can get data from the **FileUpload** control to display an image? i.e. does **Image control** have any other attribute that's used to get data, besides ImageUrl

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the `<asp:Image>` control? If so, then this is only used to render html.

```
<img src="" alt="" title="" class="" customattribute="" />
```

So what else are you wanting to do with it? If you are wanting to store an image before you save it locally, then I do not think this would be possible.

You would need to save the image from the FileUpload in between steps in order to display it.

Comment: At least, now I know what I cannot do. Thank you also for explaining to me the true nature of the <asp:Image>.

Comment: You are most welcome! Not many people thank me for my answers, so Thank you also!